# Qt creator Screen navigation

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator

I am doing screen navigation in my application for example i am moving firstwindow.cpp to secondwindow.cpp. I used below code to navigate above function but my problem is that i successfully able to see second window but at the same time my first window left opened so how do i close first or previous window.

`r1 = new secondform(this);
r1->showFullScreen();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`hide()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hide) function in order to hide a widget/window.

You should consider using [`QWizard`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html) for navigating through widgets instead of implementing the functionality yourself.

Comment: i tried hide() and close() method but i have still same problem.i am using qt creator c++.

Comment: thanks for reply but when i call hide then all window going to close.